# Why implementing a class with non public members is prohibited in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Having the following class:

```
class Trait {
    publicMethod() {
        this.privateMethod();
        // do something more
    }

    private privateMethod() {
        // do something usefull
    }
}
```

If I try to implement it in the following way:

```
class MyClass implements Trait {
    publicMethod() {}
}
```

I receive the following error:

> MyClass incorretly implements interface Trait. Property
>   'privateMethod' is missing in type 'MyClass

If I try to implement it in the following way:

```
class MyClass implements Trait {
    publicMethod() {}

    private privateMethod() {}
}
```

I receive the following error:

> MyClass incorretly implements interface Trait. Types have separate
>   declarations of a private property 'privateMethod'

If I try the following:

```
class MyClass implements Trait {
    publicMethod() {}

    public privateMethod() {}
}
```

I receive the error:

> MyClass incorretly implements interface Trait. Property
>   'privateMethod' is private in type 'Trait' but not in type 'MyClass'

The same thing happens with protected methods, and private and protected properties. So it seems that to be able to implement class all members of that class must be public.

Why implementing a class with non public members is prohibited in TypeScript?

EDIT:
Ok, implements treat classes as interfaces and because interfaces cannot have private members you cannot implement a class having non public members. But why not ignore non public members?

This question raised because I want to apply mixins to reuse code. An alternative is composition, however there is a solution using mixins and non public members.

Here is the solution:

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
        })
    });
}

interface ITrait {
    publicMethod();
}

class Trait implements ITrait {
    publicMethod() {
        this.privateMethod();
        // do something more
    }

    private privateMethod() {
        // do something usefull
    }
}

class MyClass implements ITrait {
    publicMethod() {}
}

applyMixins(MyClass, [Trait]);
```

Comment: a Class `extends` another Class and `implements` an Interface. `Trait` is a Class, not an Interface

Comment: @BrunoGrieder Actually, `implements` is used for mixins in TypeScript (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#mixins-mixin-sample)

Comment: @MartinVseticka OK. My bad, I just learned something. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, the keyword `implements` treat `Trait` class as an interface and interfaces cannot have private methods.

See rationale behind mixins here and private methods here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5070

**Edit:** It is quite easy to spot the first problem with private methods in mixins and the reason why they are not supported. What if two traits have private methods with the same name? It is imperative that they must not affect each other but that can't be easily done (consider `instance['my' + 'method']()` notation).

From [TypeScript documentation on CodePlex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Mixins%20in%20TypeScript&referringTitle=Declaration%20Merging):

> The first thing you may notice in the above is that instead of using
>   'extends', we use 'implements'. This treats the classes as interfaces,
>   and only uses the types behind Disposable and Activatable rather than
>   the implementation. This means that we'll have to provide the
>   implementation in class. Except, that's exactly what we want to avoid
>   by using mixins.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I disagree, but at least there is a reason.

Comment: Do you disagree with me? Or with the implementation of mixins?

Comment: I disagree with the sentence "the keyword implements treat Trait class as an interface and interfaces cannot have private methods.". I think this is not enough reason. Why not simply ignore non public members?

Comment: Name collisions can also occurs with public members, and the behavior is equally weird, the last applied mixin wins.

Comment: I can only add what the main contributor of TypeScript says to the issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5070#issuecomment-145166507

Comment: I still disagree, but I recognize yours is the correct answer.